# SQL Covert string to a rows in a temp table with column field and value

Tags: sql, split, varchar

I have a requirement to convert the string data into column:

```
     DECLARE @STR  varchar(max)
     set @str = 'username=tiger,password=1234$'

    I need result like the below in a temp table:
    Field            Value   //Column names
    userName          tiger  //values from the string
    pasword           1234$  //values from the string
```

Comment: so you want the username and passwords as separate rows? Or one row with 2 columns?

Comment: Thank's for the quick response,I want username and passwords as separate rows with column name field and their respective values in value column.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of assumptions here such as the format is always the same etc but it'll get you started.

```
DECLARE @STR  varchar(max)
SET @str = 'username=tiger,password=1234$'

SELECT 
    'username' AS Field
  , SUBSTRING(@str, 10, CHARINDEX(',', @str) - 10) AS Value
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'password'
  , SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%password=%', @str) + 9, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('password=%', @str))
```

Comment: Yes,thanks for your support,i was able to make it out:

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here ,we go:


       DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX)
       set @str = 'username=vmunshi,paswword=1234$'



       DECLARE @TempMain TABLE (FieldName Varchar(Max), Value VARCHAR(MAX))

       DECLARE @TempTBL TABLE (Items Varchar(Max))
       INSERT INTO @TempTBL SELECT Item FROM dbo.fn_SplitString(@Str, ','); 

          WITH CTE AS
              (
               SELECT  T.Items,
               LEN(T.Items)-LEN(REPLACE(Items,'=','')) N
               FROM @TempTBL T

                )
           INSERT INTO @TempMain
           SELECT   
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(Items,'=','.'),N+1) AS FieldName,
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(Items,'=','.'),N) AS Value
           FROM CTE

           select * from @TempMain
```

function:

```
           CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]
              (    
              @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
               @Character CHAR(1)
               )
             RETURNS @Output TABLE (
             Item NVARCHAR(1000)
                )
               AS
              BEGIN
            DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

            SET @StartIndex = 1
            IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
            BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
             END

             WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
             BEGIN
             SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

             INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
             SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

              SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
             END

            RETURN
           END
```